# Pair array element in two possible way first is currect and second is approximataly currect

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Consider the following array as input:

```
$input = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
```

I'm looking for a way to make loop though this array, writing down the possible pair of two values. In this example:

```
(pairs AB, BC and CD give out of mark). 
$output1 = array('AB', 'BC', 'CD');
```

Or

```
May has (the pairs are BC, CD, and DA gives 50 out of 100).

$output2 = array('BC', 'CD', 'DA');
```

Any input on how to get this started is appreciated!

Comment: What is the logic? Why you have `AB`, but not `AC` or `DB`?

Comment: AB, BC, CD is the possibility to append the second element with first upto the end of the array but with user arrange these an array in second output form then I have to consider this for 50% correct array. means finally I want to create two possibilities of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop the array and build the new items as following:.

```
$input = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
$res1 =array();
$res2 =array();
Foreach($input as $key => $val){
    if($key != count($input)-1) $res1[] =$val. next($input);
    if($key !=0) $res2[] =$input[$key].$input[($key+1)%count($input)];
}
```

https://3v4l.org/n28N9

Comment: Thanks, @Andreas Second array is done, but first, need some changes.

Comment: ? Mind telling me what changes? The link above seems to show exactly what you requested.

Comment: Are you running old version of php? In that case this should work `if($key != count($input)-1) $res1[] =$input[$key].$input[$key+1];`